# I've git clone, now what?

Tags: git, github

I've just cloned a repository, made some changes and now I'd like to send the author my patch. What should I do?

I cloned from github anonymously.

```
git push origin
```

?

Comment: If you have a github account, too, (or the upstream author can access your git repository somehow) read this: http://github.com/guides/pull-requests , else you should do `git diff > my.patch` and mail the patch to the upstream author.

Comment: @Boldewyn: You should put that in an answer, rather than a comment ;)

Comment: @Dan Moulding: Done. It was intended as a short remark, but with each edit the comment got longer ;-)

Comment: @Boldewyn: You should probably use format-patch, not diff, to generate the patch, so that you get all the metadata about the commit (in particular, your name as author, and the commit message).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to *commit* to your local repository, then you can *push*.

But that's not going to work probably since you aren't logged in.

Comment: So what do I do? I want my changes sent with minimal effort :)

Comment: I have a github account but I wasn't logged in when cloning. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Juanjo: Nope. Just clone the project again inside github (two clicks, if I remember correctly) and push your local changes to your github clone. Then ask the author to pull from your github clone.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a github account, too, read this: http://github.com/guides/pull-requests

Elif the upstream author can access your repository via ssh, http or the git protocol, write an email, that he can pull from there: `git pull http://example.com/cool_stuff.git`

Else you should do `git format-patch -o patchdir && tar c patchdir.tar patchdir` and mail the patch to the upstream author.

Answer (score 1):

You should first fork http://help.github.com/forking/
and then send a pull-request: http://github.com/guides/pull-requests

Answer (score 1):

minimal affort? `git diff > file.patch` and mail ;)

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit to your local repository with `git commit`

Create a fork in git (see hellvinz's answer). Push your local commit to your personal fork. Then send a pull-request to the author.